# What can be used instead of #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")?

Tags: c, sockets, visual-c++, linker

I am just working on a simple client and server program in c. 
I have realized that in order to use sockets I have to link the winsock libary file with a pragma: #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib").
I was wondering if there is another why to do it without using the pragma instruction. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, through your VC++ project settings: Linker, Input, Additional dependencies

Comment: @Prakash LoadLibrary() and then GetProcAddress() for all imported functions? What a long useless job...

Comment: Why don't you want to use the pragma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add library directly in project.

Follow the steps.

`Step 1:` Go to project settings in linker option in Additional dependency add your library name like Settings->linker->Additional dependency : add your library name.

`Step 2:` Settings->linker->Additional Library Dependency : add your library .lib path.(Ignore if it is a system library)

`Step 3:` Settings->C/C++->Additional Include Directory : Add your library header file path.(Ignore if it is a system library)

In your case as `WS2_32.lib` is a system library, you just need to go with step 1 only.

Now run your project.
It will work.

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess Ws2_32 is indeed a system libary, so step 2+3 can be ignored?

Comment: @user3497668: yes, need to go with only step 1.

Comment: I had to go a slightly different way (Solution Explorer -> Right click on project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies) in step one. However, I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 so perhaps Microsoft changed it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the linker option. In fact, that `#pragma` is just linker switch..